# Change css background image when hover

Tags: jquery

Hi i have a little problem with hovering an image. I just want my image to be replace when hovering over a text and then go back its original image after hovering. However when i hover, the images changes but it does not goes back to its original image after hover.

Here is my jquery code.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 var j = jQuery.noConflict();

 j(function () {

  j( ".click-me .hover-me" ).hover(function() {
    j( ".click-me .hover-me ul" ).slideToggle( "fast", function() {
     //change image to new image
           j(".click-me .hover-me li .clicker ").css('background-image','url(images/arrow-down.png)');
           
    });
  });
        //after hover image goes back to previous image
  j(".click-me .hover-me li .clicker ").css('background-image','url(images/arrow-right.png)');
 });

</script>
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`.hover` registers a callback, it does not immediately execute it. So there is no 'after' the call to `.hover`. In fact, the line

```
j(".click-me .hover-me li .clicker ").css('background-image','url(images/arrow-right.png)');
```

is executed *once* after the callback has been *registered*. It is *not* called after the callback has been *executed*.

Implement [`.hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
j( ".click-me .hover-me" ).hover(
  function() {
    j( ".click-me .hover-me ul" ).slideToggle( "fast", function() {
      //change image to new image
      j(".click-me .hover-me li .clicker ").css('background-image','url(images/arrow-down.png)');           
    });
  },
  function() {
    //after hover image goes back to previous image
    j(".click-me .hover-me li .clicker ").css('background-image','url(images/arrow-right.png)');
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi @Lutz Horn, i tried your code and it works as expected but the slideToggle would not close even after i hover. It would just close if i hover back.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
j(".click-me .hover-me").hover(function() {
    j(".click-me .hover-me ul").slideToggle("fast", function() {
        //change image to new image
        j(".click-me .hover-me li .clicker ").css('background-image', 'url(images/arrow-down.png)');
    }, function() {
        j(".click-me .hover-me li .clicker ").css('background-image', 'url(images/arrow-right.png)');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m4bywe00/)**

Comment: Amit add some explanation

Answer (score 1):

`.hover()` works with two functions as parameters, one for each action (mouse enter, mouse leave). I improved a little the code to prevent the repeating of selectors as much as possible:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j(function () {
    var $target = j( ".click-me .hover-me" );

    $target.hover(function() {
        j("ul", this).slideToggle( "fast", function() {
            //change image to new image
            j(".clicker", $target).css('background-image','url(images/arrow-down.png)');

        });
    }, function(){
        //after hover image goes back to previous image
        j(".clicker", $target).css('background-image','url(images/arrow-right.png)');
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi kmsdev. I tried your code. And it works just the way i expected. Thanks but there is a small problem, when i hover,  the dropdown would not close. It would just close when i hover it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   $(selector).hover(inFunction,outFunction);

   function infunction() 
   {
     //code to change image on hover
   }

   function outFunction() 
   {
     //code to change image to on leave hover
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `hover`?

On mouseenter make the first change, then on mouseleave switch it back...

https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var j = jQuery.noConflict();

     j('.click-me .hover-me').mouseenter(function(){
 j('.click-me .hover-me ul').slideToggle('fast', function(){
 //Change image to new image
 j('.click-me .hover-me li .clicker').css('background-image', 'url(images/arrow-down.png)');
 });
});
j('.click-me .hover-me').mouseleave(function(){
 j('.click-me .hover-me ul').slideToggle('fast', function(){
 //Change image to new image
 j('.click-me .hover-me li .clicker').css('background-image', 'url(images/arrow-right.png)');
 });
});

    </script>
```

Comment: @LutzHorn put this much more eloquently, below. +1 for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly at

> I just want my image to be replace when hovering over a text and then
>   go back its original image after hovering.

try utilizing `css` [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

```js
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j(function() {
  j(".click-me .hover-me").hover(function() {
    j(".click-me .hover-me ul").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

```css
.hover-me ul {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}

.clicker {
  display: block;
}
/* default, e.g.; `background:url(images/arrow-right.png)`  */
.clicker {
  background: yellow;
}
/* hover, e.g., `background:url(images/arrow-down.png)` */
.clicker:hover {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="click-me">
  <div class="hover-me">
    hover
    <ul>
      <li><span class="clicker">clicker</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```